# How to understand using tf.cond with tf.Print?

Tags: tensorflow

Look at the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant(1.0)
y = tf.constant(2.0)
z = tf.constant(3.0)
def f1():
    return tf.Print(x, [x])

def f2():
    return tf.Print(z, [z])
op = tf.cond(x>y, f1, f2)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(op)
```

I'm very puzzled, the output of tf.Print is 3.0

As we know, tf.Print(z, [z]) will output the value of `z` only when `z` is evaluated, but I don't think I have evaluated `z`.

Another question is about `tf.cond`, how does it add node to graph, for example how does add `tf.Print` to graph, I think it should relate some tensor with the return of `tf.Print`, otherwise `tf.Print` won't be executed.

I'm so puzzled.

Comment: The tensor output of a `tf.Print` op is equal to it's input. So `tf.Print(x, [y1, y2, ...])` will evaluate to `x` but with the side-effect of printing the values of `[y1, y2, ...]`. Does that begin to answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might have got the order of the arguments to `tf.cond` confused. The call:

```
tf.cond(predicate, f, g)
```

is equivalent to "if `predicate` is true then evaluate `f`, otherwise evaluate `g`"

In your example, since your predicate `x > y` is false, `f2` is evaluated

---

**Note**

Since tensorflow 1.4, `tf.cond` will accept key-word arguments `true_fn` and `false_fn`, so you can avoid any confusion by writing:

```
tf.cond(predicate, true_fn=f, false_fn=g)

# Or equivalently...
tf.cond(predicate, false_fn=g, true_fn=f)
```

Comment: My true_fn or false_fn return `tf.Print`, I'm confused about `tf.Print`, which need to evaluate tensor, but I don't evaluate tensor. You may misunderstand my question.

Comment: Perhaps I have. I thought your confusion was about seeing the value of `z` rather than `x`, but on second reading I see it is more about the nature of `tf.Print`.

Comment: Yeah, `tf.Print` works like `tf.identity`, so I can rewrite `f2` to `def f2(): z=tf.Print(z, [z]) return z`, so when it execute `f2` equals to execute `z`, and `tf.Print(z,[z])` will output the value of `z`, I just use this to debug when condition is satisfied.